# Asynchronous sequential circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis

How do I analyze a sequential asynchronous circuit? The yellow part is the one I don't get (I know how it works, but don't know how to write it when I do the analysis) [image]

Comment: This is not a straight X,Y gives a certain Z circuit, it has internal feedback (the yellow line). Since it can only have two states, 0 or 1, you can easily analyze both situations. If after that you're still confused, read this article on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First assume the yellow signal is `0`
2) Evaluate the rest of the signals based on (1)
3) From 2 you can get two outcomes: Either it is consistent - then it is a stable state. Or you get a contradiction and have a logically impossible combination (I.e. end up with yellow signal has to be `1`). In this case it is a stable state.
4) Repeat 2-3 with the yellow assumed `1`.

Done.

Comment: So it will be x AND 0 (which is 0) OR xy' (which is zero)? And x AND 0 again is 0 that becomes 1 after the not and 1 AND y gives y, which in the end is y' ?

Comment: This is not a combinatorial circuit. Your result will (or might) be a function of previous state. Like a flipflop.

Comment: I did it assuming it was 0 (your point 2).

Comment: Is that right or I am still missing something?

Comment: If the previous output of the second-level AND gate was 0, it's output will remain zero forever. Right? If it was '1', it will depend on the `x` and `y` inputs. Apparently, when the inputs cause it become zero, the circuit will get "stuck" in a single state.

Comment: But the second level AND can't give 0 because there's a not at the end, so it turns in 1.

Comment: By second-level I mean the one with the "XY'" next to it

Comment: It's an OR. Our Prof draw it this way.

Comment: Oh my.. can't he draw curved lines? Anyway, the same idea. If it was 0, the output will be `xy'`. If it was `1`, the output will be `x+xy' = x+y'`. But as you can see, if one of these expressions evaluate to the opposite value, the output won't be stable.